# Could the empty string be returned as a character when making a random choice from a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I want to get a random character from a string. In my particular use case I want a character from `ascii_letters` from the `string` package:

```
import string
import random

random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
```

Now when I check

```
"" in string.ascii_letters
>> True
```

Does this mean `""` will be one of the possible returns of `random.choice`? If not, why not? And if yes, is there a pythonic way to stop it from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the random selection is basically from a sequence, and the string sequence gives one character at a time, not the empty spaces between characters. It's the same reason you don't get the empty string from:

```py
for ch in "123": print(ch) # gives 1, 2, and 3.
```

If `choice()` was allowed to return any of the zero-width bits between characters, there is an infinity of those, meaning the chances of seeing one of the non-zero-width characters would be, to all intents and purposes, zero :-)

---

The reason you get `True` for `if "" in "something"` is due to a note in the Python docs:

> While the `in` and `not in` operations are used only for simple containment testing in the general case, some specialised sequences (such as `str`, `bytes` and `bytearray`) also use them for subsequence testing:
>
> ```py
> >>> "gg" in "eggs"
> True
> ```

There is no *single* element (i.e., character) in the string `"eggs"` that is `"gg"`, yet the example returns true, same as it does for `""`. That's because this is *sub-sequence* testing rather than containment testing.

---

You can test it if you wish, with something like:

```py
import random
while random.choice("123") != "":
    pass
print("Pax was wrong!")
```

and see if it ever prints out that statement.

I realise that's not proof since even random numbers may give you an infinite sequence of the single value `42` (for example). But it does at least *support* my contention :-)

Comment: Why is the empty string not in the iterable?

Comment: @veracruz: because, if you're allowed to return the empty spaces between characters, there are an infinite number of those before you even get to the first real character :-)

Comment: Also, the `in` operator does something completely different for strings than for any other type; bit of an arbitrary inconsistency... Compare `"" in s` against `"" in list(s)`